# Call an url with parameters from jquery in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to open a new url, pasing parameters using jquery, this is the way that im doing it,

```
  $('#BtnPrintFlujo').click(function(e) {

       var url = '@Url.Action("BillingxCashier", "Reports",new {area="Configurations" })';
       url += "/opParam=" + $("#Users option:selected").val() +
                    "&fromDate=" + $('#FromDate').val() +
                    "&toDate=" + $('#ToDate').val();

       var win = window.open(url);

       if (win) {
          win.focus();
       } else {
                    alert("Porfavor, debes permitir que se abran las ventanas emergentes o el reporte no va a salir :'( ");
               }
            });
```

but, it said this error

```
 Request.Path dangerous on the client (&).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('#BtnPrintFlujo').click(function(e) {

       var url = '@Url.Action("BillingxCashier", "Reports",new {area="Configurations" })';
       url += "?opParam=" + $("#Users option:selected").val() +
                    "&fromDate=" + $('#FromDate').val() +
                    "&toDate=" + $('#ToDate').val();

       var win = window.open(url);

       if (win) {
          win.focus();
       } else {
                    alert("Porfavor, debes permitir que se abran las ventanas emergentes o el reporte no va a salir :'( ");
               }
            });
```

you missed an question mark before first parameter,

```
url += "?opParam=" + $("#Users option:selected").val() +
```

try this

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was thinking than it works exactly like a normal url, where i pass the id,